# Gravity Forms WooCommerce Add-On Entry Doesn't Contain Order Details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I've got a setup where the user when buying a product submits their details via a gravity form using the woocomerce add-on, and then is redirected to the checkout for payment.

Everything works, I receive the filled out form and the user can purchase the product. It's just there's nothing in the form to connect it to that specific order. So when it's payed for via paypal unless their paypal email matches their email in the submitted form I have no idea who's paid for what.

I'm guessing there must be some built in way of providing this information in the form, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed the plugin since it's not free, but I did skim through the demo, so some parts might be off.

When the order is redirected to PayPal, the `custom` parameter is a PHP [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) payload that contains at least two identifiers - a number, like `304`, and a string like `"order_53031fc6a8fd6"`. The first one seems to be the lead ID, while the second one is the WooCommerce order.

When setup correctly, the return URL points to `?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal`, which is the standard WooCommerce processor which should mark the order as paid for. I imagine there is a link somewhere between the lead and the order, either on the order screen, or in the lead screen. Either way, you should be getting notifications of orders that have been paid and having no issues finding them. You should never have to manually match payments to orders, if you are then you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to find a way to display the order and account information in Gravity Forms. There is another [forum post here](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201715713-Show-Product-Add-ons-in-Orders-or-Show-Custom-Order-Fields-on-Products-) with the same question, but it was not solved.

The WooCommerce Customer/Order CSV Export plugin allows you to export a CSV of each order which does include the Gravity Forms fields, but they are all concatendated in one item_meta field, which isn't very helpful.